how to configure basedpyright to work with numpy.typing
basedpyright can't resolve a simple import numpy.typing. What should I add to my configuration to get it to work?
For instance, if I have a file a.py with a single line:
import numpy.typing as npt

I get this error when running basedpyright:
> poetry run basedpyright a.py
/home/come/programming/python/basedpyright/a.py
  /home/come/programming/python/basedpyright/a.py:1:8 - error: Import "numpy.typing" could not be resolved (reportMissingImports)
2 errors, 0 warnings, 0 notes

While mypy runs successfully on the same file:
> poetry run mypy a.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file

If I create my own virtual environment and run mypy and basedpyright directly, without poetry, I get the same result.
I checked that I do have a typing subdirectory in numpy:
> ls  ~/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/typing/
__init__.py  mypy_plugin.py  __pycache__  tests

basedpyright seems to work as expected for everything else. It's only with numpy.typing that I have a problem.
This is the pyproject.toml that I am using:
[tool.poetry]
name = "demo"
version = "0.0.1"
description = "This is the python version of the demo package"
authors = ["Come Raczy <come@omtx.ai>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
numpy = ">=2.1.0"
python = ">=3.12,<4.0"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
mypy = ">=1.11.1"
data-science-types = "^0.2.23"
typing-extensions = "^4.12.2"

[tool.mypy]
plugins = "numpy.typing.mypy_plugin"
files = ["."]

[tool.pyright]
typeCheckingMode = "basic"


The problem is caused by the package data-science-types. Removing that package resolves the problem for both basedpyright and pyright.
